# how to remember login details for a web crawling using http request and response

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to scrap a webpage which on login shows emails of members, using two Webbrowser control's im able to do it using one for login and other web browser for my required page.

since i have 1000's of urls i want to use http request and response and use regax expression to get the required output.

Is there anyway that http request remember the logins and show all the member emails?

Comment: There is a good chance that some of the sites use javascript/AJAX which is not supported/executed by httprequest!

Comment: @Yahia so is there anyother solution?

Comment: "other solution" must be something that behave like a browser... like WebKit.NET or awesomium - they are basically browser engine which can be used in .NET application (if need be headless or with UI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple, login using WebBrowser control and once done save the cookies information in a container like this:

```
           string[] array = webBrowser.Document.Cookie.Split(new char[]
                        {
                            ';'
                        });
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string cookie = array[i];
                            string name = cookie.Split(new char[]
                            {
                                '='
                            })[0];
                            string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
                            string path = "/";
                            string domain = "abc.com";
                            yummycookies.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
                        }
```

Now you have the cookies inside a container, now use HttpWebRequest with this cookie container and it be as you are already logged in as you have the login cookies.

```
 public  string getHtml(string url)
    {
        string responseData = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Accept = "*/*";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1";
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.CookieContainer=yummycookies;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            responseData = "An error occurred: " + e.Message;
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```